# Is it possible to calculate the posterior probability of any type of classifiers?

Tags: classification, probability

As i know, some classifiers such as Naive Bayes calculate the posterior probability of data and based on it produce the result.
My question is that does any classifier can produce posterior probability? 
for example how decision tree can generate it?

Answer (score 0):

Some classification models such as logistic regression and neural networks compute posterior class probabilities directly. Models based on generative models, such the quadratic discriminant and models derived from mixture densities, also compute posterior class probabilities. Decision trees can be easily adapted to output a class probability by returning the proportion of positive examples from leaves of the tree.

A prominent exception is the support vector machine, which doesn't return a probability. I think maybe someone has tried to modify it to return a probability; dunno how that worked out.

See Hastie, Tibshirani, and Friedman, "Elements of Statistical Learning" (or any of many texts) for more about this stuff. Further questions of this kind should probably go to stats.stackexchange.com.